# Convert JSON to array of objects with custom keys and values

Tags: javascript

I receive from the server a JSON string:

`{0:["aNumber","aText","anID"],1:["aNumber","aText","anID"]..`.

I must elaborate this string so that:

1. aNumber is concatenated with client side strings (say, it becomes "http://www.myurl.com/aNumber.jpg");
2. aNumber becomes the value of url in array of objects;
3. aText becomes the value of caption in the same array;
4. anID becomes the value of id in the same array;

   [{url:"http://www.myurl.com/aNumber.jpg",caption:"aText",id:"anID}.{url:"http://www.myurl.com/aNumber.jpg",caption:"aText",id:"anID"}...

I perfectly know how to do this, but I wanted to know if anyone knows if is possible to do the same thing avoiding a loop: the JSON is really huge (more than 10000 items) in a mobile context, so I was hoping in something magic to improve performances.

Comment: Some software at some level will have to iterate through the structure, unless you've got a mobile device with a 10,000-core CPU.

Comment: @Pointy: yes, but I was hoping at another level there would be better performances.

Comment: @Rocket: maybe it's not the loop itself but what you do inside its body

Comment: Do you know if this is even really a problem? Easy enough to prove, make a simple for each actually doing it. Time it on a couple of devices. See if it's acceptable. It could well be a micro optimization, if not, it can't be objectively improved upon until you've got measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through 10,000 items in a mobile context. Then try 100,000 and then 1,000,000. You'll probably see that looping is not the greatest performance bottleneck.

Comment: well, it depends on the device hardware too: 10000 is well tolerated by a "recent" device, while could slow down an older device

Comment: Defining the real target platforms and doing actual benchmarking is always better than speculation.

Comment: well, before doing benchmarks you must find what you want to compare. The loop does the job, but I was looking for something different (if there's no other way, no problem). If I could decide (I can't) I would receive data in another format, but this can't be changed (and that particular kind of array of objects feeds a third party gallery, so I can't change that one too, without changing its core and there's no time for this)...

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that, here the best solution is to convert one specific child array in the object only when you need it.

Anyway, the loop is not so long to execute, the longest is the parsing JSON String > Object.

For your loop, I would have made something like:

```
obj=JSON.parse({0:["aNumber","aText","anID"],1:["aNumber","aText","anID"]});
arr=[];
for(i in obj){
  o=obj[i]; // improve performances on big objects
  arr.push({url: "http://www.myurl.com/"+ o[0] + ".jpg", caption:o[1], id:o[2]});
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the o=obj[i], it prevent the javascript engine to run all over the object.

The best solution is anyway to make your own parser to handle this directly, and even it may not be as powerfull as the JSON.parse one written in C + the loop